# TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('|S32') and format specifier ('%.7f %.7f %.7f %s')

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, save, dtype

I'm stack saving some variables into a .dat file.
I have 4 numpy arrays build as the following: 3 of them contain floating points and one a time string. This is the type(np.array[n]) output for all of numpy.ndarray:

`<type 'numpy.float64'> <type 'numpy.float64'> <type 'numpy.float64'> <type 'numpy.string_'>`

where the last array is build with datetime module:

`hr_time.append(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time_unix).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"))`

Then I used zip and np.savetxt as the following:

```
zipped = zip(lat, lon, time_unix, hr_time)
np.savetxt("shadow_orbit.dat", zipped, fmt='%.7f %.7f %.7f %s')
```

and I get the following error:

```
in savetxt
    % (str(X.dtype), format))
TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('|S32') and format specifier ('%.7f %.7f %.7f %s')
```

Actually to me is not mandatory to save the file like that, I could save just bthe three of them. In fact as you could argue from the code hr_time is just a string showing the time_unix variable in a more human readable way, so in the future I could manage to re-adjust it, but for a quick look it will be really helpfull to have it also in the file.

Can anyone help me somehow?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: look at `zipped` before trying to use it in `savetxt`

Comment: `np.savetxt` saves a numpy array, not a `zip` object.  It will first try to turn argument into an array.  Have you tried iterating through `zipped` and writing each row directly (with that format)?

Answer (score 1):

A simpler example:

```
In [93]: x,y = np.arange(4), np.array(['A','B','C','D'])
In [94]: zipped=zip(x,y)
In [95]: zipped
Out[95]: <zip at 0x7fe56f41a780>
```

`zip` produces a 'generator' like object.  `list(zipped)` to actually see the tuples.

`np.savetxt` writes from a numpy array:

```
In [96]: np.array(zipped)
Out[96]: array(<zip object at 0x7fe56f41a780>, dtype=object)
```

But you can write the zipped tuples directly:

```
In [97]: for row in zipped:print('%.5f %s'%row)
0.00000 A
1.00000 B
2.00000 C
3.00000 D
```

Just replace the print with a file write.

`np.savetxt` does something similar

```
for row in arg:
    f.write(fmt%tuple(row))
```

but I think doing your file write directly will be easier (and just as fast).